# How to create an array of Rectangles with a Rectangle class?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on an assignment that is supposed to return an array of 10 rectangles with a random height, random width, and random color selected from a string.

The program works fine to return the objects for ONE rectangle, but how would I implement this to create an array of 10 rectangles and THEN return each one in a loop?

Here's my class file with my objects:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Rectangle 
{
    private double width;
    private double height;
    public static String color = "White";
    private Date date;

Rectangle() {
    width = 1;
    height = 1;
    date = new Date(); 
    }

Rectangle (double w, double h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
    date = new Date();
    }

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
    }

public void setHeight(double h) {
    height = h;
    }

public double getWidth() {
    return width;
    }

public void setWidth(double w) {
    width = w;
    }

public static String getColor() {
    return color;
    }

public static void setColor(String c) {
    color = c;
    }

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
    }

public void setDate (Date d) {
    date = d; 
    }

public double getArea() {
    return width * height;
    }

public double getPerimeter() {
    return 2  * (width + height);
    }

public String toString() {
    String S;
    S = "Rectangle with width of " + width;
    S = S + " and height of " + height;
    S = S + " was created on " + date.toString();
    return S;
    }
```

}

Here is my client program so far. I am setting a random height and a random width and selecting a random color from the colors String.

I would like to be able to do this for an array of 10 different rectangles:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ClientRectangle 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] colors = {"White","Blue","Yellow","Red","Green"};

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        int k;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            r.setWidth((Math.random()*40)+10); 
            r.setHeight((Math.random()*40)+10);
            System.out.println(r.toString() + " has area of " + r.getArea() + " and perimeter of " + r.getPerimeter());
            k = (int)(Math.random()*4)+1;
            System.out.println(colors[k]);

        }



    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an array of rectangles and add a rectangle to each index.

```
Rectangle[] arr = new Rectangle[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
 r.setWidth((Math.random()*40)+10); 
 r.setHeight((Math.random()*40)+10);

 arr[i] = r;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh I see, had some trouble with the formatting. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Move the `Rectangle r = new Rectangle();` inside the for loop. Initialise a Array(List) outside the loop, and keep adding the Rectangles in the loop to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You already seem to know how to declare an array of objects because you did so with an array of `String`s. The declartion for an array of `Rectangle`s is very similar:

```
Rectangle[] rects;
```

Note that you *must* also initialize the array. Since arrays are themselves objects you use the `new` operator, somewhat like when you initialize a reference variable to a single `Rectangle`:

```
Rectangle[] rects = new Rectangle[SIZE];
```

The only difference, as you can see, is that you put the size of the array inside the `[]`s. This only creates an array of *references* to `Rectangle` objects. The references are all automatically set to `null`. This means that you need to create the `Rectangles` themselves. You can do this in for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE; ++i) {
    rects[i] = new Rectangle();
}
```

You can also set the width and height of each `Rectangle` as you want. (I will leave the exact details about how to do this to the reader.)

Finally, you need to put this all in a method *other than* `main()` so that you can return the whole array (You don't return one `Rectangle` at a time) as the instructions state:

```
return rects;
```

Comment: @DanielRojas I think you are not using the word "return" the same way as programmers do. If you are interested in more details, learn about functions and how they indicate the results.